# Are nested conditional renderings possible with REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the following for a special page

```
const Pricing = () => {

  return (

  <main class="o-main">
    <section class="plan">
      <div class="plan">
        <div class="plan">
          <h1 class="plan">Select the best plan</h1>
          <p class="plan">from plan1 to plan3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
      <div class="plan">
        <div class="plan">
          <h1 class="plan">features</h1>
          <p class="plan">features of plan1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
              {isLoggedin() ? (                
                  {userPlan() === 'plan1' ? (                             
                  <FaCheckCircle />
                  <a class="plan">current plan</a>                             
                  ) : (                              
                  <a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}}>sign up</a>
                  )}                                 
              ) : (            
              <a href="/signup" class="plan">sign up</a>
              )}
      <div class="plan">
        <div class="plan">
          <h1 class="plan">features</h1>
          <p class="plan">features of plan2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
              {isLoggedin() ? (
                  <>
                  {userPlan() === 'plan2' ? (  
                  <>               
                  <FaCheckCircle />
                  <a class="plan">current plan</a>    
                  </>             
                  ) : (    
                  <>             
                  <a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}}>upgrade to plan2</a>
                  </>
                  )}               
                  </>
              ) : (
              <>
              <a href="/signup" class="plan">sign up</a>
              </>
              )}

      <div class="plan">
        <div class="plan">
          <h1 class="plan">features</h1>
          <p class="plan">features of plan3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
              {isLoggedin() ? (
                  <>
                  {userPlan() === 'plan3' ? (  
                  <>               
                  <FaCheckCircle />
                  <a class="plan">current plan</a>    
                  </>             
                  ) : (    
                  <>             
                  <a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}}>upgrade to plan3</a>
                  </>
                  )}               
                  </>
              ) : (
              <>
              <a href="/signup" class="plan">sign up</a>
              </>
              )}
  </main>
  );
};
export default Pricing;
```

`userPlan()` is a function of fetch API call that returns a string like `plan1` or `plan2`

but i am getting the following error

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token

{userPlan() === 'plan1' ? (  
             ^
```

anything am missing or the logic is not possible in react?

Comment: Can you show the context of this? What comes before `{isLoggedin()`?

Comment: updated with more details

Comment: What if you used equal instead of identical, "==" instead of "==="?

Comment: tried that...did not work either

Comment: @CertainPerformance removed the `...` with html elements..if that helps now

Comment: The code in the question does not appear produce the syntax error you describe, assuming the `onClick={` parts are fine.

Comment: are you saying it should work as is? are my nests fine the way i have them?...the error am getting is here `{userPlan() === 'plan1' ? (  ` which is first time i used it in the file, so that does not point to anything wrong?

Comment: When dealing with a syntax error, it's important to post your exact code. It looks like you've truncated it in a few places with code like `<a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}>upgrade to plan3</a>`. This line is missing a a closing brace `}` So in posting this you have introduced what seems like a different syntax error. If I fix those your code seems to parse just fine. So what is the exact code that has bad syntax?

Comment: did you focus on the error message? i fixed the closing brace...please focus on error message instead of looking for faults everywhere else

Comment: so issue was i had to add all the `<>` and `</>` within the conditionals...but sometimes it doesnt complain..and sometimes it does..i added it all everywhere and then it worked...thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was that here is what is what i really had

```
              {isLoggedin() ? (                
                  {userPlan() === 'plan1' ? (                             
                  <FaCheckCircle />
                  <a class="plan">current plan</a>                             
                  ) : (                              
                  <a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}}>sign up</a>
                  )}                                 
              ) : (            
              <a href="/signup" class="plan">sign up</a>
              )}
```

and here is what worked and removed the syntax error

```
              {isLoggedin() ? (
              <>
                  {userPlan() === 'plan1' ? (  
                  <>               
                  <FaCheckCircle />
                  <a class="plan">current plan</a>    
                  </>             
                  ) : (    
                  <>             
                  <a class="plan" onClick={() => {...}}>sign up</a>
                  </>
                  )}               
              </>
              ) : (
              <>
              <a href="/signup" class="plan">sign up</a>
              </>
              )}
```

the thing is sometimes it does not complain about the `<>` and `</>` and sometimes it does, in this case

anyone that knows why this is inconsistent, please comment below

Answer (score 0):

before using this function's return value , check if it is available:

```
isLoggedin() && userPlan() ? ...
```

Comment: Sadly, that's not going to fix a syntax error.